# Why BLAS SGEMM is slow?

Tags: openmp, eigen, matrix-multiplication, blas

I'm measuring three approaches to matrix multiplication performance: a naive blocked OpenMP implementation, Eigen, and SGEMM from MKL 2021.4.0. For simplicity all matrices are square, type `float`, size `n x n`, aligned at 64-bytes. The compiler is `GCC 8.3.1` with compilation flags `-msse4.2 -O3 -fopenmp`. OS is `CentOS 7`

I don't understand why MKL SGEMM is the slowest. Why is a naive OpenMP implementation faster than a fancy-optimized library?

**Blocked OpenMP (`BS = n / 64`):**

```
  #pragma omp for collapse(2)
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
      C[i*n+j] *= beta;

  #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i+=BS) 
  for (int k = 0; k < n; k+=BS) 
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j+=BS) 
      for (int ii = i; ii < i+BS; ii++)
      for (int kk = k; kk < k+BS; kk++)
      for (int jj = j; jj < j+BS; jj++)
          C[ii*n+jj] += alpha*A[ii*n+kk]*B[kk*n+jj];
```

**Eigen**

```
  Eigen::Map<const Eigen::MatrixXf> AM(A, n, n);
  Eigen::Map<const Eigen::MatrixXf> BM(B, n, n);
  Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXf> CM(C, n, n);
  CM.noalias() = beta*CM + alpha*(BM * AM); // fortran order!
```

**MKL SGEMM**

```
cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans,
    n, n, n, alpha, A, n, B, n, beta, C, n);
```

The google benchmark results for Intel Xeon Silver 4114, 2 sockets, 2 NUMA nodes:

```
Benchmark                                     Time             CPU   Iterations
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MatMul/OmpBlk/4096/64/real_time            1132 ms         1038 ms            1
MatMul/OmpBlk/16384/64/real_time          83668 ms        80612 ms            1
MatMul/OmpBlk/32768/64/real_time        1562980 ms      1492184 ms            1
MatMul/Eigen/4096/real_time                 878 ms          867 ms            1
MatMul/Eigen/16384/real_time              36140 ms        31629 ms            1
MatMul/Eigen/32768/real_time             259762 ms       246788 ms            1
MatMul/Blas/4096/real_time                 4091 ms         3719 ms            1
MatMul/Blas/16384/real_time              219940 ms       219581 ms            1
MatMul/Blas/32768/real_time             1773874 ms      1750015 ms            1
```

Simple average time of three runs (no google benchmark, one warm-up not included)

```
OmpBlk/4096:    1452 ms
OmpBlk/16384:  87494 ms
Eigen/4096:      818 ms
Eigen/16384:   34719 ms
Blas/4096:      4060 ms
Blas/16384:   225647 ms
```

**ldd snippet:**

```
    libmkl_intel_ilp64.so.1 => /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2021.4.0/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.so.1 
    libmkl_core.so.1 => /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2021.4.0/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so.1 
    libmkl_intel_thread.so.1 => /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2021.4.0/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so.1 
    libiomp5.so => /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/latest/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libiomp5.so
```

Comment: Try the OpenMP version without `collapse(2)` and without `schedule(dynamic)`, it may be even faster

Comment: Is MKL SGEMM multithreaded ?

Comment: Do you have multiple sockets? If you do not know, please provide the result of the `lstopo` command (assuming you are on Linux and hwloc is installed, otherwise you can install it easily). As for whether the MKL is serial or not, this is dependent of the version linked which can be known using ldd on Linux. Please specify the target OS for such question.

Comment: @JérômeRichard even if linked with a multithreaded version, the actual number of threads that are used by the MKL is not garanteed, unless it is explicitely set.

Comment: @JérômeRichard 2 sockets, added linux and ldd info

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. It looks like the parallel version is linked so it seems fine. For the number of threads, I guess you can check that with `mkl_get_max_threads()` and use `mkl_set_num_threads(n)` with various n so to check the scalability. You can also try to pin threads to core and use numactl to control the NUMA policy (which can make your code certainly up to twice slower if not properly configured). It would be great to check the code on 1 socket to see how much NUMA effect can impact the code (mainly with numactl).

Comment: Besides, I am wondering if the Eigen version returns the same results due to the Fortran ordering. That being said, I see no reason for the MKL to be so slow here with the provided informations. A minimal reproducible example would help to checks few important things like how the time is measured, how the MKL is used, what is the exact memory layout and page distributed amongst NUMA nodes, etc. Note your processor appears to support AVX-512 (and AVX/AVX-2) but you use SSE only which should be much slower likely making OpenMP/Eigen versions slower. compared to the MKL (it should use AVX-512).

Comment: Skylake 4114 CPUs do support AVX-512, but with only 1 FMA unit. By the meantime, AVX2 is also supported with 2 FMA units. Considering the frequency penalty of using AVX-512 vs AVX2, it is sometimes more effective to revert back to AVX2, or even non-AVX on these CPUs. Try playing with the [MKL_ENABLE_INSTRUCTIONS](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-linux-developer-guide/top/managing-behavior-of-onemkl-with-env-vars/instruction-set-specific-dispatch-on-intel-archs.html) environment variable. `MKL_ENABLE_INSTRUCTIONS=AVX2` would be my first try

Comment: Indeed, the frequency should drop from 2.5 GHz with SSE to 2.2 GHz with AVX/AVX-2 and 1.4 GHz with AVX-512. The frequency penalty appears to surprisingly apply even on fused AVX-512 units (that makes use of AVX-2 ones internally) of Xeon Silver processors though the overhead should not be so significant compared to one with an additional dedicated AVX-512 unit (based on reported practical user results). The overhead of the AVX-512 frequency penalty can make the code up to 57% slower. Still, that does not explain the >500% slowdown.

Comment: The optimal performance of an AVX-2+FMA 32768x32768 SGEMM on such platform should be `(2*32768**3)/2.2e9/(10*2)/(2*8*2) = 50 seconds`. For SSE-4.2 (without FMA), it is 176 seconds. Practical results are generally something like ~35% slower since AFAIK no code can fully saturate the FMA units (at least this is what happens on my Skylake PC with OpenBLAS, the MKL and my own optimized code). This means the best practical time for a SSE-4.2 SGEMM should be ~237 s while Eigen reach 260 s, and an AVX-2+FMA should reach 67 s.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, all functions have the same signature: `void matmat_mul_*(int n, const float* A_mat, const float* B_mat, float* C_out);` and return the same result. `MKL_ENABLE_INSTRUCTIONS=AVX2` speeds up MKL dgemm against `MKL_ENABLE_INSTRUCTIONS=AVX512` indeed

Comment: @Gilles where did you find the information about the number or AVX2 and AVX512 FMA units?

Comment: See [this for Skylake](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/skylake_(server)) and AVX-512 pipelines, and [this for AVX2](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/haswell_(client)#Pipeline). This is kind of hard to digest but in summary, from Haswell onward, all server CPUs have 2 AVX2 pipelines. And from Skylake onward all have 1 or 2 AVX-512 pipelines in addition. **Usually**, bronze and silver have 1, gold and platinum have 2.